# New Sub Form Field function in Joomla 3.6

Tags: joomla-3.6

I have been looking for information about this new feature of Joomla 3.6 but so far I have not find anything.

Anyone can tell me what it is about?

Thanks a lot

Comment: are you talking about `type="subform"` ??

Comment: i had the same question this morning

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## New field Subform

```
<field name="field-name" type="subform" 
    formsource="path/to/form.xml" min="1" max="3" multiple="true"
    layout="joomla.form.field.subform.repeatable-table" groupByFieldset="true"
    label="Subform Field" description="Subform Field Description" />
```

**Description**

The field allow to include any existing form into the current form. If attribute multiple set to true then the included form will be repeatable. The Field have a couple "predefined" layouts for display the subform as table or as div container, and of course it allow to use your own layout.
Field support Default values from the included form, and from JSON string in default attribute. Last have higher priority.

**Attributes:**

- `formsource` - (required) The form source to be included. Path to xml
  file or the form name to search by JForm::getInstance().
- `multiple` - The multiple state for the form field. Whether the field
  is repeatable or not.
- `min` - Count of minimum repeating in multiple mode. Default 0.
- `max` - Count of maximum repeating in multiple mode. Default 1000.
- `groupByFieldset` - Whether group the subform fields by it`s fieldset
  (true or false).
- `buttons` - Which buttons to show in multiple mode. Default
  add,remove,move.
- `layout` - The layout name for render the field inputs. Available:

  - `joomla.form.field.subform.default` - Render the subform in div          container, without support of repeating.
  - `joomla.form.field.subform.repeatable` - Render the subform in div
    container, recommended for multiple mode. Support groupByFieldset.
  - `joomla.form.field.subform.repeatable-table` - Render the subform as
    table, recommended for multiple mode. Support groupByFieldset. By
    default render each field as the table column, but if
    groupByFieldset=true then render each fieldset as the table column.

For more Information : [Subform form field type](https://docs.joomla.org/Subform_form_field_type)

Answer (score 2):

If this helps anyone, here is link for Joomla! Documentation site for [Subform field](https://docs.joomla.org/Subform_form_field_type)